# How can I use setInterval and clearInterval in two different function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What am I missing here?
I can call myInterval function, but I can't stop it with clearInterval.

```
const getData = () => {
db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql(
    "SELECT * FROM itinerary_details",
    [],
    (tx, results) => {
      var data = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i)
        data.push(results.rows.item(i));
      console.log(data) 
    }
  )
})
}
```

So I am trying to have 2 buttons with 2 different function that I can call:

to start:

```
const myInterval = () => {
   setInterval(getData, 5000)
}
```

to end the setInterval:

```
const stopData = () => {
   clearInterval(myInterval)
   console.log("STOPED")
}
```

I can see the console.log, but not calling the function myInterval

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the interval ID somwhere and when clearing, you need this one.

```js
let intervalID = null; // global

const
    startData = () => {
        if (intervalID !== null) return;
        intervalID = setInterval(getData, 5000);
    },
    stopData = () => {
        if (intervalID === null) return;
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        intervalID = null;
        console.log("STOPED");
    },
    getData = () => console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': getData');

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', startData);
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stopData);
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button> <button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still is not stopping, I can call startData in my onPress, but still is not stopping when calling stopData and is not even doing the console.log

Comment: please add some more `console.log` to test if the event is taken.

Comment: for stopData I changed to !==null and only then he console.log("STOPED"), but still it won't stop the setInterval, the data will still run every 5 seconds.